# How do I get reference to the new window in WebView2?

Tags: c#, webview2

Say, I am clicking on some tennis match on [Flashscore](https://www.flashscore.com/tennis/) web site. A new window pops up. I want to capture that second window in WebView2:

```cs
browser.CoreWebView2Ready += delegate
{ 
    browser.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += OnNewWindowRequested;
};

private async void OnNewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    var newWindow = e.NewWindow; //null
}
```

However, `newWindow` is `null`. At the same time, using `WindowFeatures`, I can get height or width of the new window:

```cs
uint height = e.WindowFeatures.Height;
uint width = e.WindowFeatures.Width;
```

How can I capture the reference to the second window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The NewWindowRequested event can let you cancel opening a new window or replace the window with your own, but you cannot have WebView2 open a new window for you and get a reference to that new window.

NewWindowRequested event scenarios:

1. Take no action in the event handler or don't subscribe. WebView2 will open a new window with minimal UI that is out of control of the end developer.
2. Set the `Handled` property on the event args to `true`. Cancels opening of the new window. If `window.open` is what was creating the new window, then the return value is `null`.
3. Set the `Handled` property on the event args to `true`, and use the `Uri` property to open the URI in the user's default browser or otherwise handle the new window outside of WebView2.
4. Set the `Handled` property on the event args to `true`, and set the `NewWindow` property to a new CoreWebView2 that you create. If `window.open` is what was creating the new window, then the return value is a new window object corresponding to the CoreWebView2 that you provided. You can obtain a new CoreWebView2 by [creating one from a CoreWebView2Environment class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environment.createasync?view=WebView2-dotnet-1.0.664.37#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2Environment_CreateAsync_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions_) or if you're using a WebView2 element in WPF, WinForms, or WinUI, you can create a new WebView2 element and use its CoreWebView2 property.

You can see some example of using [the NewWindowRequested event in our sample app](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/eecf3846b7f2b21f2727d747357da2c783b8fdb2/SampleApps/WebView2APISample/AppWindow.cpp#L826).

Comment: I guess, I need option 4. When I'm doing this in event handler: `e.NewWindow = browser.CoreWebView2;`, then I begin managing this new window. So, this one line does the trick. I didn't understand _and set the `NewWindow` property to a new CoreWebView2 that you create_. But CoreWebView2 isn't creatable. Could you elaborate more on this since that one line of code works? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer to point out the two main ways you can get a new CoreWebView2. We also need to update our .NET samples to show how to use NewWindowRequested. Thx!

Comment: Now I get it! Thanks for explanation! 

Comment: I apologize that I'm asking here, but is there way to get notifications from CoreWebView2 when HTML changes? :) I could create a new question and promise to mark your answer as accepted.  The thing is that during time the page gets modified, and I want to receive brand-new HTML. Thanks!

Comment: There's no explicit WebView2 API for that. You can use ExecuteScriptAsync to inject JavaScript that uses MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver to detect whatever changes you like, and then use WebMessageReceived / chrome.webview.postMessage to post a message from script to native when the change occurs. Or if you mean when navigating to a new HTML document, you can use the NavigationStarting event.

Comment: Thanks for a tip! I will take a look. )))

Comment: maybe i missunderstand somthing in this c++ code. in C# NewWindowRequested event handler returns BEFORE m_onWebViewFirstInitialized event handler is called. any hints?