# How could I detect new window open in c# webview2

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

I'm currently using webview2

I used `this.Topmost = true;`because the program should always stay on Top.

When using webview2, in certain sites, when the button in pressed, a new window may appear instead of changing the current window.

In this case, because `this.Topmost = true;` in the current program, the newly opened window will go down.

I want to put the current program on top and the newely opened window above it.

Is there any way to detect the newly opened window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get reference to the new window in WebView2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087294/how-do-i-get-reference-to-the-new-window-in-webview2)

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66002331/how-to-stop-webview2-from-opening-new-browser-window-rather-than-inside-the-brow/66010148#66010148 ?

Comment: @PoulBak Thanks for your answer. I found the first link before, but I didn't found the second link. the second link is helpful for me